# Bat file execution is failing via Jenkins

Tags: python, batch-file, jenkins

I have a bat file to run via Jenkins, I created bat file shortcut and made as run as administrator always.

I am calling bat file as - call "C:\Users\Factory\Desktop\runFetchBuild.bat.lnk"

when I run the bat file manually it works fine but when I run via Jenkins it is failing with below error:
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '//mds-file1/Builds/Under_Development/Nightly_Builds/'

If you see above the bat file has to access remote drive.

Comment: Does the user that runs (the) Jenkins (service) have access rights to the share `//mds-file1/Builds`?

Comment: Yes.... Manually the user credentials is able to access the //mds-file1/Builds folder, please suggest on this.